# Java - Regex issue overlapping the data

Tags: java, regex

"01:23:45 Computer science is awesome! 10:11:59 I like ICE CREAM." is what this regex is supposed to match.

This is the regex I'm using :

"(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s(.+)\s" Though it's not working...could someone please help me.

Let me specify what I needed done

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Friendly {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws IOException{
        String input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d)\\s(.+)(?=\\s|$)");
        Matcher match;
        boolean first = true;
        while ((match = regex.matcher(input)).find()){
            if (!first)
                System.out.println();
            else first = !first;
            System.out.print(match.group(1) + " ");
            String[] timestamp = match.group(1).split(":");
            int hour = Integer.parseInt(timestamp[0]) * 9;
            int minutes = Integer.parseInt(timestamp[1]) * 3 + Integer.parseInt(timestamp[2]);
            boolean isOdd = false;
            String[] letters = match.group(2).split("");
            for (int index = 0; index < letters.length; index++){
                String letter = letters[index];
                if (letter != " " && letter.length() > 0){
                    System.out.printf("0x%02X" + (index == letters.length - 1 ? "" : " "), letter.charAt(0)^(isOdd ? minutes : hour) & 0xFF);
                    isOdd = !isOdd;
                }
            }
            input = input.substring(input.indexOf(match.group(0)) + 1, input.length());
        }
    }
}
```

In this code I'm trying to parse "01:23:45 Computer science is awesome!" then get "10:11:59 I like ICE CREAM."

Sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Comment: What does not working mean?

Comment: I revised my post so it is more clear.

Comment: if (letter != " " ... do not compare strings like this. You only compare if it is the same string object, which it is probably not. Always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(?:(?!\d\d:\d\d:\d\d).)+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/42

Comment: Though when I use that it captures 01:23:45 Computer science is awesome! 10:11:59 I like ICE CREAM.

I need it to capture "01:23:45 Computer science is awesome!"

Sorry I wasn't specific, cause in my code I parse out the string and reapply the regex.

Comment: @user2481296 When it errors, does it just say "I am erroring", or does it provide more information that _may_ just be useful to us trying to help you?

Comment: It's not because of that here are the logs : 01:23:45 Computer science is awesome! 10:11:59 I like ICE CREAM.
01:23:45 Computer science is awesome!  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "45 Computer science is awesome! "
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at Friendly.main(Friendly.java:19)

Comment: @user2481296 the regex is working fine as you can see from the exception.Its the code after that which is causing problems

Comment: @vks It's not capturing correctly, please let me specify again that I need it to capture the timestamp and the message with in the regex.

Comment: @user2481296 can you please check the demo link.Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to take care of ending text.

Try this:

```
\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s.+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\s.+
```